# How to read a local csv file using Azure Data Factory and a self-hosted runtime?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Windows Server VM with the ADF Integration Runtime installed running under a local account called `deploy`. This account is a member of the local admins group. The server is not domain-joined.

I created a new linked service (File System) and pointed it to a csv file on the root of the C drive as a test. When I test the connection I get Connection failed.

```
Error occurred when trying to access the file in Folder 'C:\etr.csv', File filter: ''. The directory name is invalid. Activity ID: 1b892702-7cc3-48d5-83c7-c680d6d15afd.
```

Any ideas on a fix?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked service needs to be a folder on the target machine. In your screenshot, change `C:\etr.csv` to `C:\` and then define a new dataset that uses the linked service to select `etr.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

The dataset represents the structure of the data within the linked data stores, and the linked service defines the connection to the **data source**. So the linked service should point to the folder instead of file. It should be `C:\` instead of `C:\etr.csv`